# How do I execute shell script with java in the same shell the jar file is executed in runtime?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run a shell script to mount a USB when I detect it through my java program.

My USB detection program/class works, mounting script works too, but when run the script via Java, It is executed in a different shell and does not mount the USB for my runtime usage of the usb files through java.

My Script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb -o uid=pi,gid=pi
echo "USB drive mounted"
```

And my java program is so complex to just put it in here, but it essentially changes if " /dev/disk/by-id " had any changes and decides if a USB stick was inserted and then runs the shell script to mount it, It echoes "USB drive mounted" but when I try to interract with the files in /mnt/usb/ it is always empty, when I run the script by itself through the console, it mounts it to /mnt/usb and I can acces files

EDIT:
My java command to execute the shell is this:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/usb-connect.sh").start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(line);

usbfh.transferFiles();//transfers files from usb to device
}catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace}
```

This is giving me the error of:

`mount: /mnt/usb: special device  /dev/sda1 does not exist.`

Which is false since when the same script is executed via cmd prompt, it mounts with no errors

Comment: "It is executed in a different shell and does not mount the USB" FYI those two statements are completely unrelated, unless you're running inside a container.

Comment: So uhh I just guessed it executing the shell script in a different shell was the problem, what do you thinl the problem is here? When I mount the usb from cmd console, my code works, when I execute Usbmounting script it mounts the usb too.. Just they dont work when executed via java for some reason

Comment: How are you executing the script from your Java code? Are you checking whether something (like an error) is printed to the standard output of the execution? That may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't use comments for code or other important information that should have been in the question to begin with.

Comment: Ok edited it, thank you for being slow with me and showing how to do things

Comment: Ok, so does that code print anything? And you should check the error stream (`p.getErrorStream()`) as well.

Comment: Great idea lemme see

Comment: Edited it with the errors

Comment: Try to modify your script so that it also prints the output of `ls /dev/sd*`. I'm under the impression this is just a timing issue, that is the time that elapses between the moment you detect the usb is connected and the time you try to mount it is not enough. Also, since you're detecting it by looking at `/dev/disk/by-id`, can't you use that to specify the device? Finally, I've never seen a usb drive be assigned `/dev/sda1` on a running system, since `/dev/sda` is usually the primary hard drive

Comment: Well when I do ```sudo fdisk -l``` it says the device is ```/dev/sda1/``` also it shows partitions etc too, so I cannot just find and specify the one device

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I'm out of options :(

Comment: One last check. Does the user the application is running under have permission to mount filesystems?

Comment: Yes, it does have permissions :( ty for ur time tho!

Comment: This may not be applicable to you but you can do this with [udev rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28577/391632).